# Почему в React.js одна magnet ссылка работает с webTorrent, а другая нет?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я нашел код на codesandbox:
[1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-feynman-mvwjd9?file=/src/App.js

С использованием webTorrent библиотеки в React.js для стрима видео или фильма. В этом примере при вставке ссылки **torrentId** все запускается и видео воспроизводится, а если я вставляю свою magnet ссылку из **test** - > то ничего не происходит, даже нет сообщений об ошибке. Не пойму почему так, по документации разные способы пробовал, ни один не получается. Почему такое может быть?

Comment: выглядит как проблема с ссылкой либо файлом по ссылке